# Is there any way to add border in highcharts legend text individually?

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts, border, legend

I need to add border with legend text (legend-item) like[image]

I am trying with borderWidth but it gives a border to the whole legend area is there any possible way to do that.

Comment: Please add some reference information where you want to do the above changes.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you create a code snippet or at least post your HTML, CSS & JS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `legend.itemStyle` property with `legend.useHTML = true`.

**Code:**

```
  legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    itemStyle: {
      'border-style': 'solid',
      display: 'block',
      padding: '2px',
        'border-width': '1px',
      borderColor: 'red'
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xp24b910/1/

**API:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle